# How to load/save wxString from/to wxStream or wxMemoryBuffer?

Tags: buffer, wxwidgets, wxstring

I have my own class (nBuffer) like wxMemoryBuffer and I use it to load/save custom data, it's more convenient than using streams because I have a lot of overloaded methods for different data types based on these:

```
class nBuffer
{   // ...
    bool wr(void* buf, long unsigned int length);// write
    bool rd(void* buf, long unsigned int length);// read
}
```

I'm trying to implemets methods to load/save wxString from/to this buffer.
With wxWidgets 2.8 I've used the next code (simplified):

```
bool nBuffer::wrString(wxString s)
{   // save string:
    int32 lng=s.Length()*4;
    wr(&lng,4);// length
    wr(s.GetData(),lng);// string itself
    return true;
}
bool nBuffer::rdString(wxString &s)
{   // load string:
    uint32 lng;
    rd(&lng,4);// length
    s.Alloc(lng);
    rd(s.GetWriteBuf(lng),lng);// string itself
    s.UngetWriteBuf();
    s=s.Left(lng/4);
    return true;
}
```

This code is not good because:

1. Is assumes there are 4 bytes of data for each string character (it might be less),
2. With wxWidgets 3.0, `wxString.GetData()` returns `wxCStrData` instead of `*void`, so the compiler fails on `wr(s.GetData(),lng);` and I have no idea of how to convert it to a simple byte buffer.

Strange, but I found **nothing** googling that for hours... Also I've found nothing useful in wxWidgets docs.

**The questions are:**

1. That is the preferred, correct and safe way to convert wxString to byte buffer,
2. The same about converting the byte buffer back to wxString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arbitrary wxStrings you need to serialize them in either UTF-8 or UTF-16 format. The former is a de facto standard for data exchange, so I advise to use it, but you could prefer UTF-16 if you know that your data is biased to the sort of characters that take less space in it than in UTF-8 and if space saving is important for you.

Assuming you use UTF-8, serializing is done using `utf8_str()` method:

```
wxScopedCharBuffer const utf8 = s.utf8_str();
wr(utf8.data(), utf8.length());
```

Deserializing is as simple as using `wxString::FromUTF8(data, length)`.

For UTF-16 you would use general `mb_str(wxMBConvUTF16)` and `wxString(data, wxMBConvUTF16, length)` methods, which could also be used with `wxMBConvUTF8`, but the UTF-8-specific methods above are more convenient and, in some build configurations, more efficient.